# ICustomTypeDescriptor and Blend

Tags: wpf, expression-blend, icustomtypedescriptor

I'm working on a binding prototype for a new project and ran into a snag with Blend and binding. We're trying to us a `BindableEntity` class with the `ICustomTypeDescriptor` interface implemented. The reason for this is to allow a separation between Entity Framework and binding on the UI.

The problem we've run into is Blend using reflection instead of the `ICustomTypeDescriptor` implementation for our property descriptors. For example, when I click on the binding for one of the text blocks in the Main Window I need the `FirstName` and `LastName` properties to show up so the designer can select them. I don't want them to use a custom binding. Ironically, Visual Studio demonstrates the desired behavior.

Here is a link to the 
[Source Code](http://frontrangesystems.com/CustomTypeDescriptorPrototype.zip)

Does anyone have any ideas on how to accomplish this?